# javaFX filling/updating Tableview

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx, tableview

I have some trouble using javaFX to fill a tableColumn with some data according to a selected index from an other table.
the Table starts empty.
and then I want to fill it when the user press a button. (so far, so good)
here's what the button controller looks like :

```
@FXML
private void handleNextRequest() {
    int selectedIndex = headingTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
    if (selectedIndex >= 0)
        mainApp.updateEntity(headingColumn.getCellData(selectedIndex));
    entityTable.setItems(mainApp.getEntity());
}
```

So this calls a function from the main class which update my observable list.
The selectedIndex parameter is used to determine which data I have to load in the list (those data are located on a database which I can access via a web service, hence the "api" (which works fine)).
So here's what this function looks like :

```
public void updateEntity(String header){
    try {
        this.entity.clear();
        int i = 0;
        while(header != heading.get(i).getName()){  
            i++;
        }            
        api.getEntity(new URL(heading.get(i).getURL()), this.entity, primaryStage);
    } catch(MalformedURLException e){}  
}
```

And up to this point everything is functional. when pressing the button the function is called properly and the observable list (entity) is updated correctly. (checked and re-checked)

and then... boom.
the "setItems" function (back to the button controller) doesn't seems to like whatever I've done and throw a NullPointerException.

If someone could help me understand what the problem might be here I would be delighted !

EDIT :

here's the initialize code that I have :
I have this in the initialize method :

```
@FXML
private void initialize() {
    headingColumn.setCellValueFactory(CellData -> CellData.getValue().nameProperty());  
    entityColumn.setCellValueFactory(CellData -> CellData.getValue().nameProperty());
    showTableDetails(null);
    headingTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> showTableDetails(newValue));
}
```

and both `entityTable` and `entityColumn` declared properly.

Comment: Where do you assign `entity`? It is cleared in `updateEntity` but I can't see it being reasigned.

Comment: It is reasigned in the `api.getEntity` function.
It works fine. printed elements from the list after that shows the correct content.

Comment: Can you post the code which initializes the table?

Comment: okay, I added it to the question above. (had a little trouble with markdown ;) )

Comment: Where exactly is the `NPE` pointing to? It would be helpful to see all the  code which is involved in the `NPE`or even better to have a [MCV](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: since you talked about my MVC, I just looked at the `fxml` and noticed where I was wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured it out.
Pretty dumb mistake but the `fx:id="entityTable"` was missing in the fxml file.
thank you for helping me realizing that !